# SharePoint Online modern list view search box - add default filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, spfx, modern-experience

Is it possible to tweak list view search box (Modern) and add additional filter using SPFx?

Comment: What exactly you want to do by tweaking the list view search box? You want to set default text in search textbox?

Comment: No.. I have a very big list.. more than 200k items.. what I just need is only the items match with some content type.. currently I am typing in my searchtext AND contenttype:"<content type name>". I wanted to avoid adding AND filter manually.

Comment: You can change the list view settings & add filter on content type. Check my answer below (1st workaround).

Comment: its a big list.. encountered threshold limit issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no supported ways to tweak default list view search box using SPFx.

**Workarounds**:

If you want a permanent filter on list view, you can apply it from **View settings**.

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4#OfficeVersion=Online)

---

If you want a temporary filter/search via textbox, you can do this using query parameter in URL like:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/TestList/AllItems.aspx?view=7&q=Bold
```

[image]

**Note**: It will open a SharePoint list in search mode.